# ucrtbase.dll on win 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, windows-7-x64

i have a code, it worked ad win 10;8.1;8 but dont work on win 7 or older. Can i fix it or maybe i can embed this dll on my program. I use pyinstaller and python 3.7.7

error:

```
Сигнатура проблемы:

Имя события проблемы: APPCRASH

Имя приложения: main.exe

Версия приложения: 0.0.0.0

Отметка времени приложения: 5e11d372

Имя модуля с ошибкой: ucrtbase.dll

Версия модуля с ошибкой: 10.0.10137.0

Отметка времени модуля с ошибкой: 556ec8de

Код исключения: 40000015

Смещение исключения: 000000000005e9ff

Версия ОС: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1

Код языка: 1049

Дополнительные сведения 1: 20f2

Дополнительные сведения 2: 20f229cc03fa06192e5542b9e2c4bfef

Дополнительные сведения 3: 4180

Дополнительные сведения 4: 418060c1a3c6f66c0ad84398fedc7a01
```